# Assert.AreEqual on two objects but ignore DateTime properties

Tags: .net, unit-testing

I have a unit test where I mock the result of something which has a DateTime property which is set when I perform the action - a "CreatedOn" property. Since I can't create my result and perform the action at the same time my Assert.AreEqual always fails. How can I test that my two objects are the same Except for certain DateTime fields?

Comment: Can you show your test method code? I think if you are mocking result of something, then you can provide any return value, with any CreatedOn property value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really two options here:

1. Change `CreatedOn` after the creation time to make the properties match.  This may or may not be possible given your API.
2. Make a method that checks all of the other properties, but ignores the `CreatedOn` property.  Just use that.  This is effectively just multiple `Assert.AreEqual` calls, but on individual properties, not just the object as a whole.

Comment: This sounds like the easiest solution but not so robust. I think I might do this temporarily until I find a easy AND robust way.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do one of following things:

- You can create TimeProvider dependency for your SUT and use that provider to get current date. That will allow you to setup any current date.
- If object which you are comparing is returned by one of SUT dependencies, then you can setup mocked dependency to return exactly same object instance which you are checking in your test.

Comment: This sounds like the most robust solution but would make the implementation overly complicated.

Comment: @rushonerok unfortunately in true unit-testing you should mock all external resources (databases, files, etc) and current time is also external resource as configuration file, so yes, it should be mocked :)